# What is a fast way to compute the null space (kernel) of an row-orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there a faster way to compute the nullspace of $A \in \mathcal{R}^{m\times n} $ where A is a set of $m$ orthogonal row vectors, i.e. , $AA^T= I_{m \times m}$.

Currently, matlab's [null](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) takes several tens of seconds to get this done. Is there an approximation, that makes use of the fact, that $A$ is orthogonal, that can help me speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null() function from Matlab uses SVD. But you already know A consists of orthonormal rows, so really all you need is to find the missing "row vectors" that together with A form an n-by-n orthonormal basis. I would start by finding vectors not in the row-span of A, and apply Gram-Schmidt. But since you're using MATLAB, try qr($A^T$), which should be faster than null().